# plotting planetary orbits with python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm a compplete beginner when it comes to coding and I would really appreciate some help with this exercise. This is the information given:

These are the orbital elements that are needed to plot the (eliptical) orbits of the planets
It is a list of lists, with for each planet:
a [semi-major axis in astronomical units au]
e [the elipticity of the orbit, between [0, 1] with the higher the value to more elliptical the orbit]
I [the inclination of the orbit, i.e. the angle between the plane of the orbit and the plane containing the Earth orbit in degrees]
peri, node [these are the two angles that define the position of the ellipse in units of degree]
period [the orbital period in units of years]
Name [the name of the planet]

```
orb_elements = [
[0.3871, 0.20564, 7.006, 77.46, 48.34, 0.241, 'Mercury'],   # Mercury
[0.7233, 0.00676, 3.398, 131.77, 76.67, 0.615, 'Venus'],  # Venus
[1.0, 0.01673, 0.0, 102.93, 0.0, 1.0, 'Earth'],         # Earth
[1.5237, 0.09337, 1.852, 336.08, 49.71, 1.881, 'Mars'],  # Mars
[5.2025, 0.04854, 1.299, 14.27, 100.29, 11.87, 'Jupiter'],  # Jupiter
[9.5415, 0.05551, 2.492, 92.86, 113.64, 29.47, 'Saturn'],  # Saturn
[19.188, 0.04689, 0.773, 172.43, 73.96, 84.05, 'Uranus'],  # Uranus
[30.070, 0.00895, 1.770, 46.68, 131.79, 164.9, 'Neptune'],  # Neptune
[39.4821, 0.24883, 17.14, 113.76, 110.30, 247.94, 'Pluto'],# Pluto 
]
```

and

```
def orbitalElements2Cartesian(a, e, I, peri, node, E):
""" Convert orbital elements to Cartesian coordinates in the Solar System.

Args: 
    a (float): semi-major axis (AU)
    e (float): eccentricity
    I (float): inclination (degrees)
    peri (float): longitude of perihelion (degrees)
    node (float): longitude of ascending node (degrees)
    E (float): eccentric anomaly (radians) ; this can be an array or single value

"""

# The source of equations used:
# http://farside.ph.utexas.edu/teaching/celestial/Celestialhtml/node34.html
    
# Convert degrees to radians (using the map function, but you could have simply used (np.pi * angle/180.).
I, peri, node = map(np.radians, [I, peri, node])

# True anomaly (caculated from E and the eccentricity. Notice that for a circular orbit [e=0] theta and E are identical.
theta = 2*np.arctan(np.sqrt((1.0 + e)/(1.0 - e))*np.tan(E/2.0))

# Distance from the Sun to the point on orbit (notice again that for e=0, this is a circle with radius a)
r = a*(1.0 - e*np.cos(E))

# Cartesian coordinates
x = r*(np.cos(node)*np.cos(peri + theta) - np.sin(node)*np.sin(peri + theta)*np.cos(I))
y = r*(np.sin(node)*np.cos(peri + theta) + np.cos(node)*np.sin(peri + theta)*np.cos(I))
z = r*np.sin(peri + theta)*np.sin(I)

return x, y, z
```

This is what I should do:

Now make a 2D plot with a top view (so using  ,  of the planetary orbits)

Hints:
Since you want to plot the whole orbit (and not just a single point) you want to define an array for the eccentric anomaly that contains linearly spaced values across the entire allowed range  [0,2]  with sufficient points.
Use a for-loop this this to obtain the inputs for the 'orbitalElements2Cartesian' function:
for i, orbit in enumerate(orb_elements):
a, e, I, peri, node, period, name = orbit
Call the function with these elements as well as the array you produced for   . This will give you the arrays  ,,  and    that contain the points of the orbit to plot
x, y, z = orbitalElements2Cartesian(a, e, I, peri, node, E)
Define your plot as a function that allows you (by using an if-statement) to select one or more planets
Include the Sun by plotting a yellow marker in the center of your plot

A friend sent me this as a clue but I'm unsure what it does and would really appreciate some help as to what to do.

```
def plot_planet_orbit(planet_names):
E = np.linspace(0,2*np.pi,10000)
planets = [x for x in orb_elements if x[-1] in planets_names]

for i, orbit in enumerate(planets):
    a, e, I, peri, node, period, name = orbit
    x, y, z = orbitalElements2Cartesian(a, e, I, peri, node, E)
```

Comment: can you post the code as formatted text and not as links to images? thanks

Comment: don't paste screenshots of code, you'll get more answers then